# Cannot retrive column value from jos_users in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a question. In jos_users table there are columns referring to user details and such.[image]

I can retrieve all other columns by using

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->get('columnname');
echo $userId;
```

But why can't I retrieve column user_group_id?

It returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using Joomla 1.5, you can use the following to get the user's usergroup:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$user_type = $user->get('usertype');
echo $user_type;
```

Please bare in mind that `'usertype'` was deprecated as of Joomla 1.6 so if you ever decide to upgrade to the latest Joomla version, this code will need to be replaced.

Comment: No problem using the usertype as I've mentioned in the question. but i need the user_group_id in particular. It's an integer. Any idea how to retrieve it?